# How do I ask for reconsideration of "duplicate question"?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901422/wordpress-reports-mysql-cant-create-write-to-file-tmp-blah-myi-errcode) which was promptly marked as a duplicate. I already clearly explained that that particular question does *not* solve the problem. How can I get the duplication status removed?

I since expanded on why it does not answer the question, but I had already stated quite clearly that it "does not offer a permanent solution".

I understand that my question seems similar, the main point here is that none of those answers are sufficient. What is the best way for me to clarify my issue?

Comment: *"This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question."*

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton not sure what your comment is about - clearly OP asked new question (and linked to old one) which was closed as duplicate...

Comment: Octopus, I don't think your question is really different from the duplicate - if there would be permanent solution it should go to duplicate, but I doubt one exists. You may instead want to add bounty on the question instead of asking new one.

Comment: @Alexei, if I post bounty to the older question, do I get an opportunity to explain why none the 12 existing answers are sufficient? It would seem weird asking for bounty on a question that supposedly has a "right" answer. And indeed, that answer may be suitable for most instances of the issue.

Comment: He didn't ask a new question @AlexeiLevenkov, that's his first question regarding the issue

Comment: @gnat, I thought meta was a different breed and was more for a case by case basis. I can't very well discuss the specific situation around *my* question if I refer to a previous meta Q can I? Anyway, not an issue any more. Solved!

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton: That's the advice you see, but the advice for the OP AFAICR mentions editing to clarify.

Comment: @Octopus: How is the dupe *not* relevant? And what aspects of your question are significantly different?